# Why are my genes filtered for Gene Ontology term enrichment?

Tags: gene-ontology, functional-annotation, go-enrichment, sequence-annotation, gencode

When I enter a list of gene names into common gene ontology (GO) term enricher (e.g. MsigDB or ToppGene) only a small fraction of genes is actually used for the enrichment:

[image: msigdb gene restriction]

**I am struggling to understand why precisely only such a small number of genes is mapped here.**

My dataset is mapped with the GENCODE annotation. What annotation is the base of gene ontology? (The picture mentions entrez genes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "click here for details" saying? That link should contain an explanation of what happened.

GSEA usually requires `entrez_id` to run. If your list contains `gene_symbols`, then before enrichment, you need to convert the genes names. This can and is (always) tricky as genes are known with different names. For example, by googling I couldn't find any `AASS3` gene, but I found `AASS`, which is also named `LKRSDH`,`LORSDH`, and `LKR/SDH`. Depending on the software you are using for conversion, and the genome version used some genes will be missed. I usually run (in R) a combination of `geneSynonym` and `biomaRt` to fill the gaps in the lists.

Even better, would be to use `ensembl_id` or even better `entrez_id` directly

Comment: Hi thank you, you solved it! (1) The blue table in the picture is revealed after clicking on *click here*. (2) These interfaces work usually well with gene symbols. (3) Do you know if there are less gene with an entrez_id than specific in GENCODE? (4) Actually you pointed out right that AASS3 does not exist. It turns out I used the wrong column in my table to select the genes: AASS3 was just a unique row name for AASS